# regex to replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, str-replace

Input

```
'/api/v1' or '/_api/v1'
```

output

```
'/'
```

I could do it like this

```
const output = input.replace('/api/v1', '/').replace('/_api/v1', '/');
```

But just curious how can we take advantage of **regex in replace** method, and do it in a single shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make the underscore [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) using the `?` meta-character.

```js
// using the constructor here to avoid all that forward-slash escaping
const rx = new RegExp('/_?api/v1')
const inputs = ['/api/v1', '/_api/v1']

inputs.forEach(input => {
  console.info(input, ' becomes ', input.replace(rx, '/'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple or-condition `|`:

Regular expression: /api/v1|/_api/v1

And with javascript:

```
const output = input.replace(/\/api\/v1|\/_api\/v1/g, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `\/_?api\/v\d+`

1. `_?` is or condition with and without `_`
2. And use with `d+` it will match numeric in end of the `v1&v2`

[**Demo Regex and explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/z2aPno/2)

```js
var input1 = '/api/v1'
var input2 = '/_api/v1'

console.log(input1.replace(/\/_?api\/v\d+/g, '/'))
console.log(input2.replace(/\/_?api\/v\d+/g, '/'))
```